# Rails Mysql2::Error: Can't find file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

Any ideas on what this is and how I can fix it?

```
$ rake db:migrate
== 20150512132215 RenameNotificationSubscriptions: migrating ==================
-- rename_table(:notifications_subscriptions, :video_subscriptions)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Can't find file: './railsapp_development/notifications_subscriptions.frm' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory): RENAME TABLE `notifications_subscriptions` TO `video_subscriptions`/Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `query'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the old table name wrong `notifications_subscriptions` should have been `notification_subscriptions`. A weird error to see nonetheless.